# For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x^k|\leq \epsilon x^{2k}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus K$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $k\geq 0$ be fixed. I want to try to prove the following statement

> for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|x^k|\leq \epsilon x^{2k}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus K$?

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Assume first that $x\neq 0$. Then, we have
$$
\frac{|x^k|}{x^{2k}}=\frac{1}{|x|^k}.
$$
How to show that each time $\epsilon$ is chosen, we can find $K$ such that this expression will be less than $\epsilon$ on $K^c$? I suspect it has something with limits to do with. This expression converges to $0$ if $|x|>1$, to $1$ if $x=1$, while it does not converge for $|x|< 1$, for $k\to \infty$. Or, perhaps I should use Archimedean property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x^{2k}=|x|^{2k}$ we can just assume $x>0$.

Then $x^k\le\epsilon x^{2k}$ is equivalent to $$1/\epsilon\le x^k$$or, equivalently, $$1/\epsilon^{1/k}\le x.$$

So it is enough to  take $K=\{x||x|\le 1/\epsilon^{1/k}\}$.

Comment: Okay, that's a nice way to find $K$ explicitly. If I assume $x<0$, following your process by replacing $x$ with $-x$ to get the result $1/e^{1/k}\leq -x$, right? Then one gets $1/e^{1/k}\leq |x|$ for $x\neq 0$. What happens if $x=0$?

Comment: You do not consider $-x$. Just replace $x$ everywhere by $|x|$ in the proof. The point $x=0$ is in the deleted interval $K$.

Comment: Ok. Sorry to ask, by "the point $x=0$ is in the deleted interval $K$" you mean that $0\in K$, right?  I am not familiar with the "deleted interval", only with "deleted neighborhood".

Comment: Yes $0\in K{}{}{}{}$.